# Create TXT file in Android Nougat which is editable

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

I have created txt file which is in Internal Storage. I want to edit the file by going through file manager or any file explorer. I can update the file in Lollipop and below. but can't in Android M and Android N. It gives error as access not allowed.

```
File root = new File (Envirenment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"FolderName"); 
if(!root.exists())
 { 
root.mkdirs();
 } 
File gpxFile = new File(root, "FileName.txt");
FileWriter writer = new Filewriter(gpxFile ); 
writer.append("FileBody"); 
writer.flush(); writer.close();
```

It working on all devices including Nougat, but when I going to edit from file Explorer it is not editable in Nougat. is any permission required when file is created, as readable by others?

Comment: post your code for better understanding which one is not working.

Comment: File root  =  new File (Envirenment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"FolderName");
if(!root.exists())
{
root.mkdirs();
}

File gpxFile = new File(root, "FileName.txt");
FileWriter writer = new Filewriter(gpxFile );
writer.append("FileBody");
writer.flush();
writer.close();

Comment: It working on all devices including nougat. but when I going to edit from file Explorer it is not editable in  nougat. is any permission required when file is created ? as readable by others

Comment: First, this is not your code, unless you created your own class named `Envirenment`. Beyond that, please explain, **in detail**, how you are determining that "it is not editable".